# Unable to launch matlab after installation

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, matlab, application-launch

I have recently installed a copy of Matlab on my Linux Mint distro to a secondary hard drive. I have tried running it in different ways and none of them seems to work.

I have tried using `sudo`, and have `cd`'d into the installation directory, into the `bin` folder where the `matlab` script is and it still does not work.

`/media/.../Matlab/bin $ sudo ./matlab` simply returns `./matlab: command not found`

Am I missing something stupid here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you have found your answer by now.  If you have not, then we need some more details to answer the question.  If you run `which matlab` what is the result?  What is the return of `echo $PATH`?  Could you tell us what is output for `ls -la /media/.../Matlab/bin`?